# Cascading delete in Hibernate: What order to delete from tables?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, cascade

Within my `Java` application I am trying to run a `cascade delete` on a parent object that has children.

When when I run the application I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint  violated - child record found
```

I have searched for this error and [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora02292.php) it states that it is due to:

```
You tried to DELETE a record from a parent table (as referenced by a foreign key), but a record in the child table exists.
```

Do I need to delete all the child tables *first*? I thought the idea behind cascade delete was that it did this *automatically*?

**Code:**

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myclasses");
                EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
                Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            try {

               String hqlDelete = "DELETE FROM product WHERE price='PRICED'";
                Query queryDelete = session.createQuery(hqlDelete);
                queryDelete.executeUpdate();

               transaction.commit();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                transaction.rollback();
                throw t;
            }
```

Comment: Could you paste both entity classes?

Comment: What makes you think you are running a 'Cascade Delete'?

Comment: because within my entity there are various cascade = CascadeType.ALL annotations? Sorry I am very new to hibernate

Comment: As the book Pro JPA 2 Notes: in relation to JPQL bulk deletes "DELETE statements are applied to a set of entities in the database, unlike remove(), which applies
to a single entity in the persistence context. **A consequence of this is that DELETE statements do not
cascade to related entities. Even if the REMOVE cascade option is set on a relationship, it will not be
followed.**"

Comment: thanks I did not know this, so how can I alter my existing code to allow the DELETE statement to cascade to related entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do is so-called `bulk delete`. It is performant, but has some drawbacks:

- **does not respect cascade**
- cannot use joins (what is somewhat logical)

You can remove children entities before, what would be most performant solution.

There is also another solution, to make use of `Cascade` option (actually it's anti-pattern if many rows should be deleted) - you can iterate over entities you want to delete and call `Session.delete()` for each.

*update*

Providing that you have `@OneToMany` association between `Parent` and `Children` entity, you can simply ask for all `Children` which would be affected and remove them beforehand:

```
session
  .createQuery("DELETE FROM Children c WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p FROM Parent p WHERE p.price='PRICED' AND c IN p.children)")
  .executeUpdate();
```

Then you can safely remove your `Parent` entities:

```
session
  .createQuery("DELETE FROM Parent p WHERE p.price='PRICED'")
  .executeUpdate();
```

More concise, but way less performant would be to query for all `Parent` entities you want to delete and then remove them manually:

```
List<Parent> parents = session
  .createQuery("SELECT p FROM Parent p WHERE p.price='PRICED'");
for (Parent parent : parents) {
    session.delete(parent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so how would I alter my existing code to use this?

Comment: Im getting the error "cannot resolve method forEach" ?

Comment: @java123999 `forEach` method comes to `Iterable` interface with Java 8, anyway - it's now corrected